# Redirect duplicate pages

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to 301 redirect redirect all duplicate pages:

```
example.com/category/pagename-2
example.com/category/pagename-3
example.com/category/pagename-4
...
```

to original page:

```
example.com/category/pagename
```

`category` is the same for every page

`pagename` is different for every page

`-2, -3, -4, -5...` is the same for every page

Can you help? I always have a hard time using `.htaccess` so I prefer to ask before testing.

Comment: _“I always have a hard time using .htaccess so I prefer to ask before testing.”_ - and you probably will _keep_ having a hard time, if you don’t start making an effort yourself at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. I couldn't test it as of now, will test in sometime should work I believe.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/category/[^-]*)-[0-9]+$
RewriteRule  ^(.*) /%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this simple rule to redirect as your topmost rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(category/.+?)-\d+/?$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```